# Что происходит при быстром форматировании диска?

Tags: память, информатика

стираются все данные

производится перемещение файлов

производится проверка файлов

производится очистка таблицы размещения файлов

По моим наблюдением ответ скрывается за четвёртым параметром, но я в этом не уверен, поэтому ищу ответ на сервисе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здраствуйте!

При быстром форматировании стирается только журнал, используемый для отслеживания путей к документам. При этом система не проверяет диск на наличие битых секторов и пропускает процесс восстановления файловой системы.

Полное форматирование, в свою очередь, очищает диск от всей информации, проводит сканирование устройства на наличие битых секторов, восстанавливает файловую систему и повышает производительность.

Подробнее здесь: https://zen.yandex.ru/media/starusrecovery/ochistka-diska--polnoe-ili-bystroe-formatirovanie-5c1e067935c69400a9859e45?utm_source=serp